# overloading a member inside another member

Tags: c++

in my school assignment i need a small help

this is my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#include "ISBNPrefix.h"

class ISBN
{
    char str[11];
    char area[6];
    char publisher[8];
    char title[7];
    bool registered;

  public:
    ISBN();
    ISBN(const char*,ISBNPrefix &);

    void toStr(char*)const;
    void toStrWithStyle(char*)const;
    bool empty()const;
    bool isRegistered() const;
    bool read(istream& is, const ISBNPrefix& list);
    void display(ostream&) const;   
};

int isValid(const char* str);
```

and this is the implementation of my file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#include "ISBN.h"

ISBN::ISBN()
{
    str[0]='\0';
    area[0]='\0';
    publisher[0]='\0';
    title[0]='\0';
    registered=false;
}

ISBN::ISBN(const char* s,ISBNPrefix& p)
{
    if(isValid(s)==1)
    {
        strcpy_s(str,s);
    }
    else
    {
        *this=ISBN();
    }
}

bool ISBN::empty()const
{
    bool chk=false;
    if(str[0]=='\0')
        chk=true;

    return chk;
}
void ISBN::toStrWithStyle(char* s) const
{
    if(registered)
    {
        sprintf(s,"%s-%s-%s-%c",area,publisher,title,str[9]);
    }
    else
    {
        toStr(s);
    }
}

void ISBN::toStr(char* s) const
{
    if (str[0]!='\0')
        strcpy(s,str);
    else
        strcpy(s,"no data");
}

void ISBN::display(ostream & os) const
{
    char str[14];       
    toStrWithStyle(str);
    cout<< setw (13) <<str;
}

int isValid(const char* str)
{   
    int rc=0;
    if(str!=0)
    {
        int sum,i=0;
        sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            sum+=(str[i]-'0')*(10-i);
        if(sum%11==0)
        {
            rc= 1;
        }
    }
    else
        rc=0;

    return rc;
}

bool ISBN::read(istream& is, const ISBNPrefix& list)
{
    char str[11];
    bool quit=false;
    bool ok=false;
    char lists;

    do{
        cout<<"ISBN (0 to quit) : ";
        is.getline(str,11); //or is.get(str,11)

        if(strcmp(str,"0")==0)
            quit=true;
        else if (isValid(str)==1)
        {
            *this=ISBN(str,list);
            ok=true;
            cout<<"isbn is valid"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            *this=ISBN();
            cout<<"invalid ISBN"<<endl;
        }
    } while(!quit&&!ok);
    return !quit;
}
```

---

in the `ISBN::read` where I say

```
*this=ISBN(str,list);
```

i want to overload another member but i can't.
can anyone tell me how can i do that?

Comment: That's a) a lot of code, and b) very unformatted. Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and look around the site for some markdown tips.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, to get the best assistance it's good to include a complete example, but at the same time you should trim down/eliminate code/definitions that aren't relevant to your problem.

You should also attempt to indicate what research you have done and include any/all compiler errors warnings relevant to the problem.

Comment: Please trim down the code in your question as suggested by the others, and please also explain what you mean by "overload", as it isn't clear at all what it is you're asking. There is function overloading in C++, but I'm not sure whether this is what you're describing here.

Comment: Just to clarify are you trying to add a reference to `ISBNPrefix` as a member variable and use the assignment in an effort to reseat (change) the it?

Comment: What are you expecting `*this=ISBN(str,list);` to do? And what member function did you want to overload??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest use std::string in favour of char[]. It will save a lot of trouble. For reading ISBN I would write something like this:

```
bool ISBN::read(istream& is) 
{
    ISBN result;

    // reading into result

    std::swap(*this,result);

    return !quit;
}
```

Or even better (as a non member function):

```
std::istream& operator>>(istream& is, ISBN& obj)
{
  ISBN result;

  // reading into result

  is(!quit)
    is.clear(std::ios_base::failbit);


  std::swap(obj,result);

  return is;
}
```

In any way you should RAII classes for your resources. In your special case `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: i cannot change function prototype. these prototypes are already given by professor and my codes is to be written for these prototypes.let me say this: in the function ISBN::read i receive (istream& is, ISBNPrefix& list). I want to pass these two value to the ISBN::ISBN(const char* s,ISBNPrefix& p). how do i use these two variable and pass them?

Comment: @user2492067 Simply read an ISBN string, construct a new ISBN and swap *this with the new ISBN.